# Low fps on games and no animations after update

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, updates, games, usb-installation

I've got the Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS version and just updated my drivers. Now, I get low fps and I have no animations on my OS.

I have a suspect of what it can be, and when I first installed Ubuntu, I had to troubleshoot my computer because it showed a message saying: "initramfs unpacking failed: Decoding failed". After seeing this, I had to reinstall Ubuntu without installing the propietary drivers, and re-reinstall it with them.

Now, I have updated my machine and everything seems to be quite worse, I have no animations when I open an application or click on the applications button, and I am getting way less fps on my games. Rocking a GTX 1650, i5-9400F and 16GB RAM @ 2666 MHz.

I dual boot Windows and Ubuntu, and have the latest propietary nvidia drivers installed btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution :

To get the latest Nvidia drivers it is necessary to add the Proprietary GPU Drivers PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

Enable 32 bit architecture (if you haven't already):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 

sudo apt update
```

**Warning: Please ensure your graphics card is supported by the 450 driver before installing. _For a list of supported GPUs click here:** https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/163238/en-us

Install the 450 driver:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450
```

**Install support for Vulkan API (will be functional only if you have a Vulkan capable GPU):**

```
sudo apt install libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386
```

**Then Reboot..**