# ubuntu 20.04.1 with nvidia GPU: not responding brightness control, not responding touchpad, black window in nvidia-settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, touchpad, brightness

I have an ubuntu 20.04.1 system with a NVIDIA Quadro T2000 and an integrated Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630. After a recent ubuntu update, I have the following problems:

- I can't change the screen brightness, not with keyboard hotkeys, nor via the terminal (using `xblacklight`),
- the touchpad is not responding,
- the external monitor, connected via HDMI, doesn't recieve a signal anymore, and
- when opening `nvidia-settings` the window appeares, but it is black and emtpty.

I tried installing the nvidia drivers from a different `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`(as suggested here [Low fps on games and no animations after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299673/low-fps-on-games-and-no-animations-after-update)), but that did not change anything. Via the *additional drivers* I changed back to the `nouveau` drivers; again, no change.

The biggest issue is the maximum screen brightness which blasts my eyes away. I'm fine with only using the intel graphics card - I can switch to my windows partition if I need graphics power.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 20 release. There are two quite different releases: 20.04 and 20.10.

Comment: Thx for the Info :) I added the correct ubuntu version.

Comment: Did you try `xrandr`? Which is not the same thing but at least it that might help until you find a solution. I have the same problem.

Comment: Just tried ```xrandr``` - sadly did not change anything :/